# Pandas Dataframe merge without duplicating either side?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, duplicates

I often get tables containing similar information from different sources for "QC". Sometime I want to put these two tables side by side, output to excel to show others, so we can resolve discrepancies. To do so I want a 'lazy' merge with pandas dataframe.

say, I have two tables:

```
df a:                   df b:
    n   I   II              n   III IV
0   a   1   2           0   a   1   2
1   a   3   4           1   a   0   0
2   b   5   6           2   b   5   6
3   c   9   9           3   b   7   8
```

I want to have results like:

```
a merge b

    n   I   II  III IV
0   a   1   2   1   2
1   a   3   4       
2   b   5   6   5   6
3   b           7   8
4   c   9   9
```

of course this is what I got with merge():

```
a.merge(b, how='outer', on="n")

    n   I   II  III IV
0   a   1   2   1.0 2.0
1   a   1   2   0.0 0.0
2   a   3   4   1.0 2.0
3   a   3   4   0.0 0.0
4   b   5   6   5.0 6.0
5   b   5   6   7.0 8.0
6   c   9   9   NaN NaN
```

I feel there must be an easy way to do that, but all my solution were convoluted.

Is there a parameter in merge or concat for something like "no_copy"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like you can do it with the information given alone, you need  to introduce a cumulative count column to add to the merge columns. Consider this solution

```
>>> import pandas
>>> dfa = pandas.DataFrame( {'n':['a','a','b','c'] , 'I'   : [1,3,5,9] , 'II':[2,4,6,9]}, columns=['n','I','II'])
>>> dfb = pandas.DataFrame( {'n':['a','b','b']     , 'III' : [1,5,7]   , 'IV':[2,6,8]  }, columns=['n','III','IV'])
>>>
>>> dfa['nCC'] = dfa.groupby( 'n' ).cumcount()
>>> dfb['nCC'] = dfb.groupby( 'n' ).cumcount()
>>> dm = dfa.merge(dfb, how='outer', on=['n','nCC'] )
>>>
>>>
>>> dfa
   n  I  II  nCC
0  a  1   2    0
1  a  3   4    1
2  b  5   6    0
3  c  9   9    0
>>> dfb
   n  III  IV  nCC
0  a    1   2    0
1  b    5   6    0
2  b    7   8    1
>>> dm
   n    I   II  nCC  III   IV
0  a  1.0  2.0    0  1.0  2.0
1  a  3.0  4.0    1  NaN  NaN
2  b  5.0  6.0    0  5.0  6.0
3  c  9.0  9.0    0  NaN  NaN
4  b  NaN  NaN    1  7.0  8.0
>>>
```

It has the gaps or lack of duplication where you want although the index isn't quite identical to your output. Because `NaN`'s are involved the various columns get coerced to `float64` types.

Adding the cumulative count essentially forces instances to match with each other across both sides, the first matches for a given level match the corresponding first level, and likewise for all instances of the level for all levels.

Comment: very clever using cum count. much cleaner than the one solution in which I force the index to match between two df's.